# Scaling keeps resetting after set keyframe in Blender action

Tags: animation, scale

I'm new to Blender animation. I'm working on an action for my animation. In this action, I scaled a bone like the photos below. But when I play action, it keeps the same scale and the values didn't interpolate. When I move the cursor between frames, it also doesn't make any action.

What did I miss here guys ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

my first 3d animation professor used to answer every question with the same initial answer... "Did you apply Loc/Scale?" not applying it to your mesh can result in the stranges things...

Also, I fail to see what is changed? your settings for scale are the same on frames 3 and 5. It looks like you put whatever you keyframed is on frame 0, and frames 1 - 20 all have the same data... since your animation is set to run from frame 1 to 20 I don't believe it ever reaches frame 0 to take on whatever changes you made in that frame...

...and what change are you making anyway? a single frame in the begining of the animation with out anything to change too just makes the single change to the entire timeline... you need a starting value and a target value.. such as the scale of x in frame 1 being 1, the scale of it on frame 10 at 2, and the scale of it at frame 20 being put back to 1, (which would cycle the bone up and down with a bit of a hitch at the end...)

Anyway, I could easily be wrong, but I think your best bet is to keyframe inside your animation timeline, and make sure you have applied your mesh's rot/scale

Comment: Thanks @richwoo. I did made a change. In frame 0, i put scale value in default value (ex : scale x,y,z - 1,1,1). And i changed the value of scale z down to 0.8 in the frame 5 that i thought it would made a animation of bone 9 scale down. But when i move around from frame 0 and frame 5 to see how animation work, the value didnt interpolate and the value of scale z in frame 0 become the same with frame 5 (i lost here).

Comment: Btw did I make wrong way to apply scale on mesh ? Because I do it in basic way that I will make change scale on pose mode (the left screen) and insert keyframe to action timeline (right screen).